# How can i turn on the debugging? ADB if my phone is locked and i forgot the PIN

Tags: android, adb

Im locked out of my phone and there are ways to bypass through ADB, but the ADB is not turned on and i know there should be a way to turn it on somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery the PIN through the FindMyDevice site. Log in select the device then chose to lock it. This will prompt you to enter new details i.e. a password or PIN to unlock the device with. All you should need is the associated Google account.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely should be out of luck unless you got i.e. [Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/find) enabled and can control your device from there. If not then maybe you are rooted or at least have bootloader unlocked? If so, then you can install i.e. [TWRP](https://twrp.me/about/) and "tweak" your device from there disabling i.e. pattern or pin lock from its terminal. If not, then your chances are getting low, however in similar situation I faced once, I managed to exercise some desing bugs of android and get out of it. But that was years ago, so perhaps this is no longer the case, yet you may want to take a look at this post [Unlocking pattern locked network-less LG G-Slate v909](http://wfmh.org.pl/carlos/blog/2014/12/22/unlocking-pattern-locked-network-less-lg-g-slate-v909/)